# Jquery - can not use plugin?

Tags: jquery, function, plugins

i'm trying to use a scrollbar plugin written with jquery : tinyscrollbar.
you can find it here : [website about tinyscrollbar jquery plugin](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)
i use jquery 5 with this command :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and i cal it just after :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
    });
</script>
```

and finally here is the html code :

```
<div id="scrollbar1">
    <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">
            <?php echo $content;?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have a bug while loading the plugin (or another, i've tried many...) : Firebug tell me
$("#scrollbar1").tinyscrollbar(); is not a function.

but the script is loaded and i've try to make an alert and that work perfectly
have you got an idea???

PS : sorry for my english... it's not my language ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the plugin.  So far all you have loaded is jquery.

Comment: many many many thx !!!! it is working great when i load in <head> the jquery, then i load and implement tinyscrollbar just before the </body>.....

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js file

If you download the example on the website then you will see the jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js in the js folder

Or you can link to it here

http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js

You also need to add the CSS to it

The website you link to has CSS styles like this

```
#scrollbar1 { width: 520px; clear: both; margin: 20px 0 10px; }
#scrollbar1 .viewport { width: 500px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
#scrollbar1 .overview { list-style: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb .end,
#scrollbar1 .thumb { background-color: #003D5D; }
#scrollbar1 .scrollbar { position: relative; float: right; width: 15px; }
#scrollbar1 .track { background-color: #D8EEFD; height: 100%; width:13px; position: relative; padding: 0 1px; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb { height: 20px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb .end { overflow: hidden; height: 5px; width: 13px; }
#scrollbar1 .disable{ display: none; }
```

Working example

http://jsfiddle.net/ChiBlaaa/SEWm2/

Comment: it always says to me there is no tinyscrollbar function